# How to split integers that contains strings, such as 73101P

Tags: string, split, integer

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'element': ['COGS', 'Other current assets', 'COGS','COGS', 'Other current assets', 'COGS'], 'account_number': ['5721-ES', '1101', '5721-ESP', '73101L', '73230K', '11106' ]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df
```

I need only the numbers without letters for converting them to numeric values afterwards.

However, I can't split these integers for instance 73101K

```
df.account_number = df.account_number.apply(lambda x: x.split('-')[0])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `findall()` that finds every digit (`\d`) and then join it together afterwards:

```py
df["account_number"] = (
    df["account_number"].str.findall(r"\d").str.join(sep="").astype(int)
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                element  account_number
0                  COGS            5721
1  Other current assets            1101
2                  COGS            5721
3                  COGS           73101
4  Other current assets           73230
5                  COGS           11106
```